# grouped data new column if a column includes a specific condition

Tags: r

I have a new Problem with my groupedData: I now want to add a new column that always says yes for a group, when I the column Caffeinefactor has a "yes" in the this group and always say so, if the column Caffeinefactor has only "no" and not a single "yes" in it.

I have tried the following code, but do not get the wished results:

```
Anycaffeine <- Data2 %>%
  setDT(Data2) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(PATIENT.ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Anycaffeine = ifelse(colSums(Caffeinefactor == "yes") > 0, "Yes", "No"))
```

My Data looks something like this:

```
DF = structure(list(PATIENT.ID = c(210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 
210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 
210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 210625L, 220909L, 
220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 220909L, 
220909L, 220909L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 
221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 221179L, 
221179L, 221179L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 
301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 
301705L, 301705L, 301705L, 303926L, 303926L, 303926L, 303926L
), PATIENT.TREATMENT.NUMBER = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Caffeinefactor = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
"yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
"yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
"yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", 
"yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"
)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fe7f7002ee0>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in the `mutate` code

1. `colSums` - on a logical vector (`Caffeinefactor == "yes"`) wouldn't work as `colSums/rowSums` require a `dim` attribute i.e. it works with `data.frame/matrix/tibble` etc.
2. `ifelse` is not really needed as we require only a single value as output in logical expression i.e. the aim is to check if there is `any` value of 'yes'.  So, `"yes" %in% Caffeinefactor` returns a TRUE/FALSE of length 1 and this is converted to a numeric index to select "No", "Yes" from a vector (`c("No", "Yes")`)

```
library(dplyr)
Data2 %>% 
  group_by(PATIENT.ID) %>% 
  mutate(Anycaffeine = c("No", "Yes")[1 + "yes" %in% Caffeinefactor]) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the fast reply! Do you also know how I can now count the number of groups that have a yes and a no?